# TextBox Control Source with Nested IIF Statement is Returning Same Column Regardless

Tags: ms-access

I'm not very experienced with Access, and I did not create this Access database, so please bear with me, but I will try to give all the necessary information.

There is a textbox in a Report that should return the value from one of 3 possible columns based on the value of another column.

In short, if Allowance Type is "Per Case" Then TextBox Value = Value From Case Column

Here is the statement I have most recently tried in the Control Source:

```
=IIf([Allowance Type]="% Off Invoice",[Freight Paid % OI],IIf([Allowance Type]="Per Pound",[Freight Paid / LB],IIf([Allowance Type]="Per Case",[Freight Paid/_Case],"")))
```

In this example, the value from the "Freight Paid / LB" column is returned every time no matter the Allowance Type.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Freight Paid % OI, Freight Paid / LB, Freight Paid/_Case are the 3 columns used, and which is used should correspond to the Allowance Type.

The reference for this specific attempt was from https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=192667

Comment: I see no syntax issues with your `iif` statement. Have you ascertained that the `Allowance Type` field is definitely changing? You could alternatively use a `Switch` statement to avoid the nesting.

Comment: @LeeMac thanks for taking a look. I do believe the `Allowance Type` is changing because the report generated will have various values in the allowance field, so it's not the same value every time. But even with the allowance changing, I still get the `Per Pound` result even when the `Allowance Type` is `Per Case` or another.

Comment: I would suggest temporarily creating three new textboxes on your form with the Control Source of the first set to: `=[Allowance Type]="% Off Invoice"` the Control Source of the 2nd:  `=[Allowance Type]="Per Pound"` and the Control Source of the 3rd: `=[Allowance Type]="Per Case"` You can then see whether or not the condition is being validated.

Comment: @LeeMac sorry for the delayed response. I did just try that and I can see that it is at least validating the condition. A "-1" appears in the box corresponding to the Allowance Type, while the other boxes remain with a 0.

Comment: Each of the textboxes should contain a `-1` (i.e. `True`) as the value of `Allowance Type` takes different values - is this not the case?

Comment: @LeeMac well not all 3 textboxes are, one textbox at a time is. For example, when `Allowance Type` is `% Off Invoice` then the 1st textbox (`=[Allowance Type]="% Off Invoice"`) has a `-1` and the other two textboxes have a `0`, which my understanding is that is exactly what we want it to be, correct?

Comment: Correct - I wanted to verify that was the case. I have added an answer which offers an alternative suggestion for you to try. I'm running out of ideas on this one unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, assuming that all of the referenced field names are correct, I see no syntax errors present in the code for your `IIf` statement and we have then also ascertained that the test expressions are being validated as expected.

```vb
=IIf
(
    [Allowance Type]="% Off Invoice",
    [Freight Paid % OI],
    IIf
    (
        [Allowance Type]="Per Pound",
        [Freight Paid / LB],
        IIf
        (
            [Allowance Type]="Per Case",
            [Freight Paid/_Case],
            ""
        )
    )
)
```

As an alternative suggestion, you could try using a simpler `switch` statement, which avoids the need for nested expressions:

```vb
=Switch([Allowance Type] = "% Off Invoice", [Freight Paid % OI], [Allowance Type] = "Per Pound", [Freight Paid / LB], [Allowance Type] = "Per Case", [Freight Paid/_Case], True, "")
```

This is structured in the following way:

```vb
=Switch
(
    [Allowance Type] = "% Off Invoice", [Freight Paid % OI], 
    [Allowance Type] = "Per Pound",     [Freight Paid / LB], 
    [Allowance Type] = "Per Case",      [Freight Paid/_Case],
    True, ""
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be pulling the correct values! I wonder though, is there anything I could add to have it use the format of the value it returns? Sometimes the result is a %, sometimes its a whole number. The values show that way in the table it is pulling from but when it is returned in this box it always shows as just the one format that the box is set to (for example %). Can I take the value and format from the source?

Comment: @TBoulz Glad you got it working! Your subsequent question regarding formatting may be better posed as a separate question, but note that formatting is not part of the data. As such, you would either need to render the value of the textbox as a string using the `Format` function, or set the formatting of the textbox through VBA using an appropriate Event handler.