# Formatting Report Textbox After Returning Value

Tags: vba, ms-access

this is a follow-up post to my original post at [TextBox Control Source with Nested IIF Statement is Returning Same Column Regardless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522950/textbox-control-source-with-nested-iif-statement-is-returning-same-column-regard/53548742?noredirect=1#comment94059724_53548742)

Lee Mac was able to help me get the appropriate syntax to return 1 of 3 potential values based on the value of another textbox. Now I am struggling to get the returned value in the appropriate format.

The values can be Currency or Percent, and they would be in the same textbox, so I've been trying an Event procedure to format the value, but no change is occurring.

My latest attempt, which results in the value always being #.####:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format()

If Me.Allowance_Type = "% Off Invoice" Then
    Me.txtbox4.Value = Format(Me.txtbox4.Value, "0.00%")
End If
If Me.Allowance_Type = "Per Pound" Then
    Me.txtbox4.Value = Format(Me.txtbox4.Value, "$###,###.##")
End If
If Me.Allowance_Type = "Per Case" Then
    Me.txtbox4.Value = Format(Me.txtbox4.Value, "$###,###.##")
End If

End Sub
```

I have also tried various other Events like `Report_Load` etc, and I've tried changing the line:
`If Me.Allowance_Type =` to `If Me.Allowance_Type.Value =` but that results in `#Name?`

Is it possible to have 1 text box that can be conditionally formatted as Currency or Percent? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a trend I see all too often in Access tagged questions:  
(1) OP posts a good question  
(2) The question fails to encapsulate all you need to know to answer  
(3) Answerers give reasonable advice based on what was presented  
(4) OP says 'it didn't work'  
(5) All further attempts to engage OP go ignored.  
I am starting to think that these questions aren't worth the effort. A much better bet would be a Teamviewer session so someone experienced can help the OP through their issues.

Comment: Sorry, I have not been able to come back to this issue yet, unfortunately. My other tasks must take priority over this Access, as this is more of an "as time allows" sort of task. I will be reviewing the answers provided shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do an expression in ControlSource and eliminate VBA.

`=Format([fieldname], IIf([Allowance_Type] LIKE "Per*", "Currency", "Percent"))`

Or include this formatting in the procedure that returns the value.

`=Format(Switch([Allowance Type]="% Off Invoice",[Freight Paid % OI], ([Allowance Type]="Per Pound",[Freight Paid / LB], [Allowance Type]="Per Case",[Freight Paid/_Case]), IIf([Allowance_Type] LIKE "Per*", "Currency", "Percent"))`

Format events only trigger in PrintPreview or direct to printer, not Report View.

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I like the idea of eliminating VBA, and its great to know that Format events don't trigger in Report View.

For the expression, do you mean to put this in the TextBox that the value is being returned in? As of now, I currently have the following expression in ControlSource of that TextBox:

`=IIf([Allowance Type]="% Off Invoice",[Freight Paid % OI],IIf([Allowance Type]="Per Pound",[Freight Paid / LB],IIf([Allowance Type]="Per Case",[Freight Paid/_Case],"")))`

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.Format` property, as in:

```
If Me.Allowance_Type = "Per Case" Then
    Me.txtbox4.Format = "$###,###.##"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it and it didn't change anything, I got the `#Name?` results. Then I changed the Event from `Detail_Format` to `Details_Format` and I got numbers, but still not in the correct format.

Comment: `Detail_Format` is the standard name of the Report Detail section event handler. Did you rename the Detail section or one of the other sections to "Details"?
Try setting all the options to the *same* format (different from the "Text Format" property) in your code. Do you get that format? Or is nothing happening?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I did not rename the section, it is still "Detail". If I'm understanding @June7 answer, then the format event would not be triggered in Report View. So I think I may be beating my head against the wall over and over with this VBA, since I'm trying a Format event that may never come.

Answer (score 0):

Per [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53548742/7531598) in your other question, if you allow yourself to convert the data to a string, as opposed to retaining the original data type (and hence original precision), then you can use the `Format` function directly in your `Switch` expression, e.g.:

```
=Switch
(
    [Allowance Type] = "% Off Invoice", Format([Freight Paid % OI],  "0.00%"),
    [Allowance Type] = "Per Pound",     Format([Freight Paid / LB],  "$###,###.##"), 
    [Allowance Type] = "Per Case",      Format([Freight Paid/_Case], "$###,###.##"),
    True, ""
)
```

Otherwise, I would suggest using an event handler to change the `.Format` property of the textbox, triggered on the `AfterUpdate` event of the form control bound to your `[Allowance Type]` field.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I'm attempting the `AfterUpdate` of the `[Allowance Type]` field, but I must say that my inexperience with Access has me a little lost on this...

This is the event I created in the Report:


<Private Sub Allowance_Type_AfterUpdate()

If Me.Allowance_Type = "% Off Invoice" Then
    Me.PaidCase.Format = "0.00%"
End If
If Me.Allowance_Type = "Per Pound" Then
    Me.PaidCase.Format = "$###,###.##"
End If
If Me.Allowance_Type = "Per Case" Then
    Me.PaidCase.Format = "$###,###.##"
End If`>



It seems to not be calling this event at all.